# I got an error code [unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list]

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have input form and this has a textarea field named Address. My input data has lines break for example `111Address\n234\n456`. After submitting the form, the data confirm page is displayed and I want to verify the output data has the same format of the input data and correct data.

I tried to use `document.evaluate` in the console, it returns to the text with correct format. But when I write code, it returns the error.

```
$(document.evaluate("//td[text()='Address']/following-sibling::td", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue).text()
```

I tried to fix the error but it didn't work. Please help me check my code.

```
        String locator = "//td[text()='Address']/following-sibling::td";
        String actualText = (String) js.executeScript("return $(document.evaluate('" + locator + "', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue).text()");
        Assert.assertEquals(actualText, inputText);
```

Comment: I think your problem comes from quote, try with \" instead of ' in your actualText ( ... .evaluate(\""+locator+"\" ....)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it and it worked.